# RabbitMQ not serialize message, error convert

Tags: jackson, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I've seen some related questions here, but none worked for me, the rabbit will not serialize my message coming from another application.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException: No method found for class [B
```

Below my configuration class to receive the messages.

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration implements RabbitListenerConfigurer{

    public final static String EXCHANGE_NAME = "wallet-accounts"; 
    public final static String QUEUE_PAYMENT = "wallet-accounts.payment";
    public final static String QUEUE_RECHARGE = "wallet-accounts.recharge";

    @Bean
    public List<Declarable> ds() {
        return queues(QUEUE_PAYMENT, QUEUE_RECHARGE);
    }

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE_NAME);
    }

    private List<Declarable> queues(String ... names){
        List<Declarable> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            result.add(makeQueue(names[i]));
            result.add(makeBinding(names[i]));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static Binding makeBinding(String queueName){
        return new Binding(queueName, DestinationType.QUEUE, EXCHANGE_NAME, queueName, null);
    }

    private static Queue makeQueue(String name){
        return new Queue(name);
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2MessageConverter jackson2Converter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory myHandlerMethodFactory() {
        DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
        factory.setMessageConverter(jackson2Converter());
        return factory;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureRabbitListeners(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(myHandlerMethodFactory());
    }
}
```

Using this other configuration, the error is almost the same:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [br.com.beblue.wallet.payment.application.accounts.PaymentEntryCommand]
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {

    public final static String EXCHANGE_NAME = "wallet-accounts"; 

    public final static String QUEUE_PAYMENT = "wallet-accounts.payment";
    public final static String QUEUE_RECHARGE = "wallet-accounts.recharge";

    @Bean
    public List<Declarable> ds() {
        return queues(QUEUE_PAYMENT, QUEUE_RECHARGE);
    }

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE_NAME);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    private List<Declarable> queues(String ... names){
        List<Declarable> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            result.add(makeQueue(names[i]));
            result.add(makeBinding(names[i]));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static Binding makeBinding(String queueName){
        return new Binding(queueName, DestinationType.QUEUE, EXCHANGE_NAME, queueName, null);
    }

    private static Queue makeQueue(String name){
        return new Queue(name);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with these settings, or what's missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> No method found for class [B

Means there is a default `SimpleMessageConverter` which can't convert your incoming `application/json`. It is just not aware of that `content-type` and just falls back to the `byte[]` to return.

> Class not found [br.com.beblue.wallet.payment.application.accounts.PaymentEntryCommand]

Means that `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` can't convert your `application/json` because the incoming `__TypeId__` header, representing class of the content, cannot be found in the local classpath.

Well, definitely your configuration for the `DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory` does not make sense for the AMQP conversion. You should consider to use `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` bean definition and its `setMessageConverter`. And yes, consider to inject the proper `org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter` implementation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.7.3.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-conversion

From the Spring Boot perspective there is `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` to configure on the matter:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-using-amqp-receiving

Comment: Ty Artem, the problem is that I was not configuring the factory in the consumer method:
@RabbitListener(id = "listenerPayment", queues = RabbitConfiguration.QUEUE_PAYMENT, containerFactory="myFactory")